# DialogFragment Bundle putSerializable: Sometimes giving NotSerializableException

Tags: android, android-fragments, bundle, serializable, android-bundle

I have a object, that has other objects inside. I need to pass that object to a FragmentDialog, so I made that object Serializable and it's working perfectly in my device.

```
public static SelectTeamDialog newInstance(Data data) {
    SelectTeamDialog dialog = new SelectTeamDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putSerializable(ARG_PARAM1, data);
    dialog.setArguments(args);
    return dialog;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    if (getArguments() != null) {
        data = (Data) getArguments().getSerializable(ARG_PARAM1);
    }
}
```

The problem is that I'm seeing some `NotSerializableException` reported in google developer console, so for some reason, in some devices, is giving `NotSerializableException`.

It's important to say that Data object is very big, and has a lot of objects inside, with a lot of objects inside. And not all those objects are serializable, but I noticed that when you are passing the bundle to a Fragment or DialogFragment is not necessary that all the sub-objects contained in a serializable objects are serializable to pass that parent object with putSerializable in a bundle.

I know it because it's working in my device and 95% of the devices. But if I try to pass this serializable object with non serializable objects inside to an Activity with a bundle, it requires to make all the sub objects serializable too (I can't do it because then it gives outofmemory when serializing). Why is not necessary when passing it to a Fragment but it's necessary when working with Activities?

And why it's this giving me some exceptions reported in the developer console if it's working for me and for the 95% of the devices that are using this application?

Comment: "I noticed that when you are passing the bundle to a Fragment or DialogFragment is not necessary that all the sub-objects contained in a serializable objects are serializable to pass that parent object with putSerializable in a bundle" -- yes, it is necessary. "I know it because it's working in my device and the 95% of the devices" -- not when those arguments are getting put into the saved instance state `Bundle` and being passed across process boundaries.

Comment: "Why is not necessary when passing it to a Fragment but it's necessary when working with Activities?" -- because `Intent` extras *always* get passed across process boundaries. Fragment arguments may or may not (e.g., depending on whether `onSaveInstanceState()` gets called). Perhaps you should switch from arguments to some other mechanism, such as a `ViewModel`, to retain your data across configuration changes.

Comment: umm, so, @CommonsWare, if I put all the classes serializable, then, the few NotSerializableException will dissapear?

Comment: @CommonsWare why it's onSaveInstanceState() getting called if my app is not allowing configuration changes?. I think that you mean that this is being called when "passed across process boundaries"

Comment: "if I put all the classes serializable, then, the few NotSerializableException will dissapear?" -- it would depend on whether or not that is possible. For example, a `View` is not serializable, no matter what annotation you put on it. "why it's nSaveInstanceState() getting called if my app is not allowing configuration changes?" -- the user could press the HOME button.

Comment: "I think that you mean that this is being called when "passed across process boundaries" " -- the saved instance state `Bundle` is held by a core OS process, in case your process gets terminated but the user is eligible to return to the activity. See https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/parcelables-and-bundles, particularly the last paragraph.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `Serializable` really gets serialized, then you will crash with a `NotSerializableException` when the serialization encounters something that it cannot handle.

With an `Intent` extra, when you use the `Intent` to start an activity, start a service, or send a system broadcast, all extras will get serialized. Doing any of those things involves inter-process communication (IPC), even if the resulting activity/service/receiver happens to be in your app. So, when you pass a partially-`Serializable` object as an `Intent` extra, you will crash with a `NotSerializableException` quickly.

Fragment arguments are not necessarily serialized. They will be if `onSaveInstanceState()` is called, as arguments automatically become part of your saved instance state. It is possible that a fragment might not get called with `onSaveInstanceState()` very often, and so a partially-`Serializable` object as an argument might survive. However, inevitably, somebody will press HOME or otherwise switch to another app, and `onSaveInstanceState()` will get called. Then, your partially-`Serializable` object argument will give you a `NotSerializableException`.